# std::move argument passed by value

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, move-semantics

I need some help regarding this piece of code:

```
void foo(std::promise<std::string> p) {
    try {
        std::string result = "ok";
        p.set_value(std::move(result));
    } catch (...) {
        std::current_exception();
    }

}

int main() {
    std::promise<std::string> promise;
    std::future<std::string> f = promise.get_future();
    std::thread t(foo, std::move(promise));
    t.detach();

    std::string res = f.get();

    return 0;
}
```

What's the meaning of the std::move() usage? Is `p` passed by value (so a copy)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` is local variable inside `foo`. Before `foo` is invoked, `p` must be created. There are two possibilities to create it: by copy constructor or by move constructor. `std::promise` is movable class, it cannot be copied. So only way to create it is call `promise(promise&&)` - move constructor. By

```
std::move(promise)
```

you are casting `p` to `promise&&`, then the compiler can select `promise(promise&&)` to move `promise` from main into `p` inside `foo`.

So no copy of `promise` is made here.

Comment: what if I have `void foo(std::promise<std::string>&& p)`?

Comment: Then no copy nor move operation is performed. You have just Rvalue reference to promise from main inside foo function. Inside `foo` you can decide what you want to do with this promise, you can move it, or just read its content.

Comment: So in the first case I'm moving `promise` to `p`, in the second one `p` is just an alias for the rvalue reference of `promise`, is that correct?

Comment: Reference is just alias for object. In second case you can treat `p` as `promise` from main, just you are accessing `promise` by using different name. So yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Technically it casts to `promise&&` which then becomes an rvalue expression of type `promise` which then binds to the move ctor arg `promise&&` :D

Comment: Isn't `std::move(result)` usage wrong in the `foo` function? Will `result` be out of scope before `f.get()` is invoked?